# JOIN Delete In postgresql

Tags: postgresql, function

I'm trying to translate one mssql stored procedure in to postgresql function. Inside that, i have to perform a delete based on values in two temp table.
MSSQL sp part will looks like this

```
DELETE a FROM resource a 
JOIN #tmp_resources r on (a.inuri=r.resource_uri)
JOIN #tmp_resource_old p on(a.outuri=p.outuri)
```

How can i convert the same in to Postgresql function. Is it possible to do the same in postgresql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could phrase the delete using exists logic:

```
DELETE
FROM resource a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #tmp_resources r WHERE a.inuri = r.resource_uri) AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #tmp_resource_old p WHERE a.oururi = p.outuri);
```

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe You are the resident Postgres expert on this site.  You may post this alternative as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use PostgreSQL's `DELETE ... USING`:

```
DELETE FROM resource a 
USING "#tmp_resources" r, "#tmp_resource_old" p
WHERE a.inuri=r.resource_uri
  AND a.outuri=p.outuri;
```